# Issue fetching role assigned in Dynamic Group using the user in LDAP search filters

Tags: ldap, federated-identity, pingfederate

I have the following use case:

1) Roles are assigned to Dynamic Groups

2) When a user entry is given, the group's role is to be fetched.

If role of "View only" is defined against a Dynamic Group :

```
DN=ou=groups,ou=group1,cn=subgroup1,dc=example,dc=com
```

And the memberURL is set as :

`ldap://dc=people,dc=dev,dc=example,dc=com??sub?(Type=external)`

A user with credentials John Doe is created with Type=external. For base DN as dc=example,dc=com and subtree selection. How to filter such that I get the role value?

I have tried putting filter as:

```
memberURL=ldap://dc=people,dc=dev,dc=example,dc=com??sub?(Type=external)
```

which results in no output.

Comment: What's the LDAP provider? PingDirectory? eDirectory? OpenDirectory?

Comment: It is PingDirectory.